# Store session array in DB

Tags: php, sql

```
<?php               
include 'connection.php';
session_start();
$noteinfo=array();
$noteinfo['note']=$_POST['note'];
$_SESSION['noteinfo']=$noteinfo;

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['note'])) {
            echo "Dobavete Komentar";
        }if (!empty($_SESSION['noteinfo'])) {
            $check=mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['userinfo']['fname']);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_fname,user_mname,user_lname,user_login,user_email,user_phone) VALUES ('$_SESSION['userinfo'][0]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][1]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][2]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][3]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][4]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][5]}')";
        $sql1= "INSERT INTO addresses (address_line_1,address_line_2,address_zip,address_city,address_province,address_country) VALUES ('$_SESSION[adr1]','$_SESSION[adr2]','$_SESSION[zip]','$_SESSION[city]','$_SESSION[provinciq]','$_SESSION[durjava]')";    
        $sql2="INSERT INTO notes (note_text) VALUES ('$_SESSION[note]')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
            echo "Added";
        if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql1)) {
            echo "Added";
            if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql2)) {
                echo "Added";
                header("refresh:3 ; url=profile.php");
            }
        } 
        }else{
            echo "Error";
        }
    }else{
        header("refresh:1 ; url=zapiski.php");
    }
```

?>

When i complete my 3 forms for users info,i store them in sessions array and after the third step i want to add the whole information from the arrays in my Database.But when i click the submit button,my db is filling only with ID's and no data.

```
session_start();
$userinfo=array();
$userinfo['fname']=$_POST['Fname'];
$userinfo['mname']=$_POST['Mname'];
$userinfo['lname']=$_POST['Lname'];
$userinfo['login']=$_POST['login'];
$userinfo['email']=$_POST['email'];
$userinfo['phone']=$_POST['phone'];
$_SESSION['userinfo']=$userinfo;
```

This is the first array,just like the other 2 .

Comment: print before you insert into db

Comment: You need to remove the `[*]` inside your query think

Comment: What to print before insert ?

Comment: print the session array

Comment: Only add Array[0]} in my first row in one of the tables now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$_SESSION
This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.

`<?php`
       `include 'connection.php';` 
        `session_start();`  
        `$noteinfo=array();` 
        `$noteinfo['note']=$_POST['note'];`  
        `$_SESSION['noteinfo']=$noteinfo;`

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['note'])) {
            echo "Dobavete Komentar";
        }if (!empty($_SESSION['noteinfo'])) {
            $check=mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['userinfo']['fname']);
```

`$sql`=`"INSERT INTO users (user_fname,user_mname,user_lname,user_login,user_email,user_phone) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['userinfo']['fname']}','{$_SESSION['userinfo']['mname']}','{$_SESSION['userinfo']['lname']}','{$_SESSION['userinfo']['login']}','{$_SESSION['userinfo']['email']}','{$_SESSION['userinfo']['phone']}')";` 
           `$sql1`=`"INSERT INTO addresses (address_line_1,address_line_2,address_zip,address_city,address_province,address_country) VALUES ('$_SESSION[adr1]','$_SESSION[adr2]','$_SESSION[zip]','$_SESSION[city]','$_SESSION[provinciq]','$_SESSION[durjava]')";`
           `$sql2="INSERT INTO notes (note_text) VALUES ('$_SESSION[note]')";`  
            `if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {

                echo "Added";
            if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql1)) {

                echo "Added";

                if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql2)) {

                    echo "Added";

                    header("refresh:3 ; url=profile.php");

                }`
            `}

            }else{

                echo "Error"; 
            }`
          `}` `else{`

```
    header("refresh:1 ; url=zapiski.php");
}
        }
```

`?>` 
[PHP $_SESSION visit this link](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `indexes(0,1,2,....)` instead of `(fname, mname, lname,....)`. So you should update line following

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_fname,user_mname,user_lname,user_login,user_email,user_phone) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['userinfo'][0]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][1]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][2]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][3]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][4]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][5]}')";
```

with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_fname,user_mname,user_lname,user_login,user_email,user_phone) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['userinfo']['fname']}','{$_SESSION['userinfo']['mname']}','{$_SESSION['userinfo']['lname']}','{$_SESSION['userinfo']['login']}','{$_SESSION['userinfo']['email']}','{$_SESSION['userinfo']['phone']}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error inside your first query, you're missing `{` This `'$_SESSION['userinfo'][0]}',` should be '{$_SESSION['userinfo'][0]}'.

Also, consider removing the indexes from the variables; this `'{$_SESSION['userinfo'][0]}'.`  to `'{$_SESSION['userinfo']}'`.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending wrong information as values.
You should write for example `VALUES ('{$_SESSION['userinfo']['fname']}',...` inted of

`VALUES ('$_SESSION['userinfo'][0]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][1]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][2]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][3]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][4]}','{$_SESSION['userinfo'][5]}')"`